# What is the best way to move decimal point in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on project where you can make payments with credit card.
I have booking system from what I get "price" and then it sends this price to merchant online payment page.
My problem is that booking system sends price in decimal. Like `123.45`.
But merchant accepts only this format: `12345`. And after receiving this format it ads decimal point automatically.

**I need to convert this "price" without decimal point. In other words move it to right. What is the best function or solution to do that?**

For now I'm using `round()` function and add two zeros (00). But this way is only if I really use rounded up prices.

```
$price = $_POST['price'];

$price = round($price) . '00';
```

I expect the output `123.45` to be `12345`. Other example `123.00` to be `12300`.

Comment: Why not just multiply by 100?

Comment: Thanks @ReddHerring. This solved my problem. I was really struggling with this.
I always attend to complicate things. :) I was confused when my online merchant didn't answered this simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
   $withoutDecimal = $withDecimal * 100;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Careful... you may lose precision. I had to switch to using bcmul()

```
 $version=22.0220;
 $int1=(int)($version*10000); // $int1 is 220219 (oops)
 $int2=(int)(bcmul($version,10000)); // $int2 is 220220 (correct)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need more flexible solution. For example, Bitcoin has 8 decimal places, US dollar - 2

```
function price_minor_units($dollars, $decimals = 2)
{
    return $dollars * (10 ** $decimals);
}

function price_major_units($cents, $decimals = 2){
    return $cents / (10 ** $decimals);
}
```